# Get ALL Mailboxes via EWS (Exchange WebServices) - not my own but also shared and group mailboxes

Tags: directory, exchangewebservices

Can anyone provide me with a .NET (C# / VB) sample of how to get all mailboxes that I have access to ?

I have only been able to get my OWN mailbox via EWS - not ALL THE OTHER mailboxes that I also have access to through Outlook.

I don't have the names nor the id's of these mailboxes but isn't it possible to retrieve ALL mailboxes - including my own - that I am allowed to see - just as I can in Outlook ?

I am using Autodiscover to get my mailbox like this: [`service.AutodiscoverUrl("xxxx@ee.dd")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd634273%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) - this will perhaps only get my own mailbox and not all the rest?

Please help !?

Comment: `Autodiscover` is only applicable when talking about locating your Exchange host - it has nothing to do with mailbox access or resolution. How does Outlook know about what mailboxes you have access to - did you add them, or how was Outlook made aware of them?

Answer (score 2):

The way I got around this was to define the group mailbox in question as a "mailbox" object and then obtain the FolderID for the particular folder.

1. Define mailbox object

   ```
   Mailbox gpmailbox = new Mailbox("mailbox@yourdomainname.com");
   ```
2. Get the FolderID (in this case, the Inbox)

   ```
   FolderId gpInbox = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, gpmailbox);
   ```
3. Use FolderID in your normal code (in this case I'm obtaining 100 messages)

   ```
   ItemView view = new ItemView(100);        
   FindItemsResults<Item> results = hookToServer.FindItems(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, gpmailbox), view);
   ```

The key is to grab the FolderID of the folder you need.  Hope this helps.

Edit: I also failed to note that my object "hookToServer" is simply the ExchangeService object.  Here's how I defined it:

```
        ExchangeService hookToServer = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
        hookToServer.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        hookToServer.Url = new Uri("TheExchangeServer")
```

I also used this as reference:
[EWS 2007 Group Mailbox Guide](http://arturito.net/2010/06/14/c-sharp-accesing-shared-mailbox-in-exchange-web-services-2007-service-pack-1-and-downloading-attachments/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by [Using Autodiscover to get user settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633650(v=exchg.80)), this is a completely separate service to the one with the AutodiscoverUrl method.

The setting name you need is AlternateMailboxes, this will give a collection of all the 'other' mailboxes you have access to. You might then add the user's default mailbox to get a complete list.

In c#:

```
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover;  // from nuget package "Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices"

    internal List<string> GetAccessibleMailboxes()
    {
        AutodiscoverService autodiscoverService = new AutodiscoverService("outlook.office365.com");
        autodiscoverService.Credentials = networkCredential;
        var userSmtpAddress = networkCredential.UserName;

        GetUserSettingsResponse userresponse = autodiscoverService.GetUserSettings(
            userSmtpAddress,
            UserSettingName.AlternateMailboxes);

        var alternateMailboxCollection = (AlternateMailboxCollection)userresponse.Settings[UserSettingName.AlternateMailboxes];
        var smtpAddressList = alternateMailboxCollection.Entries.ToList().Select(a => a.SmtpAddress).ToList();

        smtpAddressList.Add(userSmtpAddress);

        return smtpAddressList;
    }
```